# Indicate maximum amount of people?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, travel

I'm currently developing a website for a travel agency. I need to display the maximum amount of people for when the user books a cabin. For example, some cabins can have up to four people at most and two of them must be adults. Other cabins can not be booked if you have small children with you, etc etc..

I've been trying some different options, for example a icon of person and greater or lesser than signs (<4, >2).

Is there a set standard for how to indicate this?

Comment: There are *many* ways to indicated a  constraint like maximum number of guests.  Unfortunately without some idea of what your interface looks like, this question cannot be specifically answered because you're essentially soliciting a list of alternatives which is not a good format for StackExchange.  Please add a sketch or wireframe to show us what your interface looks like.

Comment: Do you just need to indicate the maximum or also a minimum? At the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider how [AirBnB shows the maximum number of guests allowed in a location](http://www.airbnb.com).

They start by asking the user to put in their number of guests.

[image: AirBnB Search]

If it's missed here, the user can change it on the next screen, where they have the same dropdown as on the previous search. This time though, the results will dynamically update as the user changes their number of guests.

[image: Dropdown in search]

Finally if it isn't caught at both of those places, each individual listing will show the user the maximum number of guests that are allow. It's predominantly displayed at the top right below the title and price

[image: Info]

For your application, I would consider doing something along the lines of AirBnB's info panel in each listing. Here, you could display how many guests are allowed, if children/pets are allowed, and other relevant information (number of beds/bathrooms, extra amenities, etc.)

Comment: This is a nice approach that I think will work nicely. Thanks, +1!

Answer (score 2):

Most travel websites suck when it comes to anything other than single guests or couples, especially with children. In many cases, you have to special case kids even more:

- Infants usually don’t count, but may require a crib.
- Toddlers may stay for free if sleeping in bed with their parents, but sometimes have to pay for breakfast, though probably not full price.
- Older children may get an extra bed, perhaps for free, or are dealt with the same as adults.

What’s more, the exact ages for when someone is considered a baby, toddler, child, adult or senior vary considerably.

Anyhow, if 4 is your maximum, you can get away with icons. That’s less practical with 16+ guests obviously. You may follow Booking.com where room rates are listed by maximum occupants with simple head and torso icons. If, optionally, a certain number of kids is included with the price they’re given after a plus sign. If more than 4 adults can sleep in an apartment or suite, their number is shown with digits.

[image: Booking.com various max. guest symbols] [image: Booking.com many max. guest symbols]